# Чтение из файла C#

Tags: c#

Делал так:

```
 FileStream stream = new FileStream("SettingsForSpamer.txt", FileMode.Open);
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
 string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
 stream.Close();
 numUDtaskbarValue.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(str);
```

Но значение все равно не менялось. Запись в файл происходит нормально, но данные не могу загрузить. Где ошибка?

Comment: Значение чего не поменялось? Не считалось в str или не удалось сконвертить прочитанное?

Comment: Проверьте, не кидает ли метод `Convert.ToDecimal` исключение

Comment: В исключение не кидает, не поменялось значение numericupdown

Comment: А где в приведенном коде работа с `numericupdown`?